# As a British citizen, will I be able to continue to use the EU passport lanes in other EU countries during the transition period after 31st Jan 2020?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, uk-citizens, brexit

The UK is scheduled to leave the EU bloc on 31st Jan 2020. As a British passport holder, will I be entitled/able to continue to use the EU passport lanes in other EU countries after that date *whilst the transition period of 21 months* lasts? (I fully understand that it is impossible to say what will happen after that period).

*Note*: I'm aware that Brexit is a controversial topic, and I'm deliberately asking to avoid any debates on the rights, wrongs, merits, fairness, unfairness, etc. of the situation, I'm just seeking practical advice.

*Other note*: I realise the same question also 
applies in reverse to EU passport holders travelling to the UK. Feel free to cover that too!

*Correction*: As pointed out in the comments below, the transition period is 11 months, not 21 months.

Comment: The transition period is currently scheduled to last 11 months (until the end of 2020) not 21 months. Bets are open to see if it will be extended :-) It was scheduled to last 21 months back when Brexit was supposed to happen in March 2019.

Comment: @jcaron BoJo doesn't want to extend it, but he's been screwed over in the past by Remainer MPs in parliament, so...

Comment: @Crazydre BoJo has nobody to blame but himself when, as a consequence of making unrealistic commitments, his commitments cannot be kept.

Comment: @Crazydre Conservative Party Remainers have been thrown out of the party and are no longer a “problem”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing will change during the transition period; as such you'll be able to enter the Schengen Area indefinitely, without your passport being stamped and using the EEA lanes.

The nature of the transition period is negotiating future rules; the rules, therefore, remain unchanged in the meantime.

*Source*: https://www.gov.uk/visit-europe-1-january-2021

Comment: Thanks. I’ve seen some statements to other effect elsewhere (may well be out of date/rumour of course) - do you have a source you can link to?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Remainer propaganda, the same suggesting Brits will need a visa for short-term Schengen visits and vice-versa (LOL!) Anyway, https://www.gov.uk/visit-europe-1-january-2021

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Even that page is incorrect on one point: it says that, after the transition period, your passport will need to have 6 months. That's bull; it's 3 months beyond the intended stay

Comment: @AndrewFerrier it's not remainer propaganda; it's confusion: some sources discuss a prospective no-deal exit, which isn't materializing.  Those sources will say that citizens of the UK will have to go to the non-EU queue, because that's what would have happened had there been no withdrawal agreement.  But there is a withdrawal agreement.  It's important to identify which kind of brexit the various descriptions of post-brexit circumstances are covering, and to disregard the ones that concern the so-called "hard" brexit.

Comment: @phoog What's propaganda is that Brits would need to join the non-EU queue even during the transition period, and that they will at any point whatsoever need a visa for short-term visits. After the transition period, yes, Brits will need to join the non-EU queue unless otheriwe agreed. Also, there is still a chance of no deal, if no concerete deal is agreed on by the end of the transition period. Because the withdrawal deal was just that, a withdrawal deal stipulating a transition period for talks, whereby anything can change.

Comment: @Crazydre yes, though I would suspect that it was more misunderstanding than propaganda, your comment mostly correct.  There is a chance, however, that visas will be required for short-term visits (contrary to your first sentence, but consistent with your last sentence).  It seems a very remote chance, but if the talks during the transition period go particularly badly, it could happen.

Answer (score 2):

> When it comes to passport control, during the transition period, UK nationals will still be allowed to queue in the areas reserved for EU arrivals only.

https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-51194363

Nothing changes until December 31st 2020.